# Adding legend with geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I need to add the legend for some geom_point I am adding in a geom_line graph. The example goes below.

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(1111)
```

## My Objects

```
Sum <- sample(1:50, 10)
year <- c(1990:1999)
index.one <- sample(0:1, 10,replace=TRUE)
index.two <- sample(0:1, 10,replace=TRUE)

df <- data_frame(Sum, year, index.one, index.two)
```

## Graph

```
graph <- ggplot(df, aes(x=year,y=Sum))+ geom_line() +
geom_point(data=df[df$index.one==1,], aes(x=year, y=Sum), colour="red", 
fill="red", shape=22) +
geom_point(data=df[df$index.two==1,], aes(x=year, y=Sum), colour="blue", 
fill="blue", shape=22) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1990,1999, by=1))
```

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjbhT.png)

I need to add the legend for the blue and red points in the graph.

Thank you!

Comment: you need to set the colors within `aes` in `geom_point`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add a geom for each colour. Colour is an aesthetic that you connect to a variable, in your case `index.one` (or .two but they are confounded).

Your example is a bit more tricky because you added `geom_line`. No problem, just add the aesthetic to `geom_point`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=Sum)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=as.factor(index.one))) + geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(`1`='blue', `0`='red'))
```

Additionally, because `index.one` is numeric, ggplot2 will try to use it as a continuous variable, but it is really a discrete, hence the `as.factor`.

[image]

*Edit:* I've noticed that you do not have a point at 1995. Simply replace the value in `index.one` for the corresponding year with `NA`, and the point will not be plotted. It will not affect the line because that draws it value from a different variable.

Comment: And how do you suggest me to exclude the NA level from the legend?

Comment: Use argument `na.translate=FALSE` in the function `scale_colour_manual`.

Answer (score 1):

This uses `tidyr::gather()` to create a long data set, then filters the points that it's only plotting the points where value is equal to 1.

```
library(tidyr)
df1 <- gather(df, index, value, 3:4)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = year, y = Sum)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(data = df1 %>% filter(value == 1), 
             aes(colour = index, fill = index), shape = 22) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1990,1999, by=1)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```